# Save dataset contents to variant array – VBA vs VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, recordset

In VBA it is very simple to define an array, read a recordeset with ADO (a simple accdb table) and then populate the array with the info from the recordset. Say I have a table with 3 columns, A is dates, B is people names and C is the number of steps each person made during a day. Because we deal with numbers and strings, it's simple to just define a variant array:

```
Dim RS_CON As Object, RS_DATA As Object
Dim  connString as String, queryString as string
Dim OutputArr() as variant
Set RS_CON = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set RS_DATA = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS_CON.Open connString
queryString="SELECT * FROM [TableName]"
RS_DATA.Open queryString, RS_CON, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
OutputArr =RS_DATA.GetRows(RS_DATA.RecordCount)
```

The resulting array has 3 columns and all the rows of table, without even specifying the dimensions of the array. In addition, the array holds various data types.
But who do I do the exact same thing in VB.NET?

```
    RS_CON = New OleDbConnection With {
        .ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" &
        sourceFld & dbFileName & "; Persist Security Info=False;")
    }
    Try
        dtSet = New DataSet
        dtTables = dtSet.Tables
        queryString = "SELECT * FROM [TableName];"
        RS_CON.Open() '---> Open Connection To The DataBase File.
        dtAdapt = New OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, RS_CON)
        dtAdapt.Fill(dtSet)

        Dim Y() As Array '---> DOES NOT WORK!!

        RS_CON.Close()
```

Thank you for any hints/clues/guidance.
Stefan

Comment: _But when I do the exact same thing in VB.NET?_ The code that you've provided isn't the _exact same thing_. The first code block you've posted is ADO (see [Recordset Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-ado?view=sql-server-ver16)), while the second code block is [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview)

Comment: Can't you just use the strongly typed dataset that .NET provides for you when you add the database to your project?

Comment: I don't see anything that will give you an array of results from multiple rows in the framework classes in `System.Data`.  It's easy enough to get the results for a single row into a vector of `Object` but combining it into a table will be more difficult.  That having been said, this looks a lot like an XY problem; what do you want to do with this variant array?

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the data. You shouldn't even be trying to do the exact same thing in VB.NET because, for one, you can't and, for two, there are better options. Which option you take depends on what you want to do with the data. Try to "convert" code form a different VB variant to VB.NET is pretty much never a good idea. What you should so is determine what it is that you want to achieve, then determine the best way to achieve it. For instance, if you want an array or collection of objects containing your data, you should be using a data reader to read the data.

Comment: Maybe this is a result of long-term habit, but while coding in VBA I found out that reading data from a db File into memory and then manipulating the data anyway I want (say computing average values in a column then diving all the members of the column by the average to 'normalize' the data) produces quick results. So basically (1) read data (in memory), (2) manipulate data, (3) save results in Excel has been my MO for years. I want to do the same thing in VB.NET, it's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DataRow.ItemArray` property to get your row as an array.

`Variant`s don't exist in VB.NET, use `Object` instead.

I'd also recommend filling a `DataTable` instead of a `DataSet`.

(NOTE: for MS Access you will need to change to ODBC objects, the code below is for Sql Server)

```
Dim connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Timeout=10;Database=Junk;Integrated Security=True;"
Dim strSql As String = "SELECT [Id], [Code], [Value] FROM [Table1]"
Dim dtb As New DataTable
Using cnn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
  cnn.Open()
  Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, cnn)
    dad.Fill(dtb)
  End Using
  cnn.Close()
End Using
Dim y() As Object = dtb.Rows(0).ItemArray
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the solution that I found and works for me is quite simple and executes fast. I simply declared an array AS OBJECT, called RawArr (from 'raw data array') and dimmed it accordingly.

```
        Dim nrRows As Integer = (dtTables(0).Rows.Count - 1)
        Dim nrCols As Integer = (dtTables(0).Columns.Count - 1)
        Dim RawArr(nrRows, nrCols) As Object
        For i As Integer = 0 To nrRows
            For j As Integer = 0 To nrCols
                RawArr(i, j) = dtTables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)
            Next
        Next
```

This works very fast. The size of the dataset is roughly 7300 rows x 9 columns and it takes just a second to read it from Access and populate the RawArr.